# C# oledbconnection Update doesn't work

Tags: c#, oledb

The code in question:

```
public static void updateItemAmount(int item_id, int delta)
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        // create command with placeholders
        cmd.CommandText =
            "UPDATE Items SET amount_total = amount_total+@delta WHERE item_number=@item_id;";

        // add named parameters
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
        {
            new OleDbParameter("@item_id",item_id),
            //new OleDbParameter("@delta",delta),

        });
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@delta", OleDbType.Integer).Value = delta;

        // execute
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

I keep getting the "Error" message even though I verified that the item_id is correct. Why is that?

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: The `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of affected rows. In your case the code executes correctly but no rows are affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple minutes later I found the problem. Apparently parameters have to be bound in order (?). This fixed it:

```
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
            {
                new OleDbParameter("@delta",delta),
                new OleDbParameter("@item_id",item_id),

            });
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@delta", OleDbType.Integer).Value = delta;
```

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem